# Can not start google cloud shell with custom image

Tags: google-cloud-shell

I can not start google cloud shell with custom image when using link https://shell.cloud.google.com/cloudshell/editor?cloudshell_image=DOCKER_IMAGE_URL.

I get error: "Unable to connect to the Cloud Shell Editor. If you continue to receive this error, try clearing your cookies and validating you are not behind a proxy. If you continue to have issues, please send us feedback.".

It's only work, when I change image to base image "gcr.io/cloudshell-images/cloudshell:latest".

Comment: My mistake, I using Artifact Registry, but cloud shell only support Container Registry :(